# as3 json object filtering

Tags: json, actionscript-3, filter

I have an object array like this one. In javascript I could filter and map this things to get my result. I am totally lost in getting the entries for age >= 20 && age <= 27. Ok I can step through each object, but is it possible to use a function to filter this out?

regards

```
 var arr:Array = [
    {
        categories:["a", "b", "c"],
        users:["John", "Steve"],
        id:1,
        information:{
            age:"30",
            color:"red"
        }
    },
    {
        categories:["d", "e","c"],
        users:["Martin", "Jason"],
        id:2,
        information:{
            age:"25",
            color:"blue"
        }
    },
    {
        categories:["d", "c"],
        users:["Robert"],
        id:3,
        information:{
            age:"26",
            color:"green"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you work with an array of objects, each object has its properties. You can write a function to filter out only objects you are interested in.

```
function byAge(item: Object, ...rest): Boolean {
    const info: Object = item && item.hasOwnProperty('information')) ? item['information'] : null;
    if (info && info.hasOwnProperty('age')) {
        const age: int = info['age'];
        return age >= 20 && age <= 27;  
    }    
    return false;
}

... 
const filtered: Array = arr.filter(byAge);
```

You can find more info in Adobe documentation: [Array::filter](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter())

Comment: Not sure I understand what do you mean under passing the age into the function. Filter function is equal to manual iteration through the array. It will call the `byAge` function for each item in array. (Same way as it does in js.)

Comment: something like this: http://blog.code4hire.com/2010/09/as3-array-filter-function-with-multiple-parameters/